# How to use today & tomorrow button with bootstrap-datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

[image]

I've made this with bootstrap-datetimepicker. But I need today & tomorrow button & layout should be as below. How can I do that?

[image]

**Html Code:**

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <label class=" text-info">Depart</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <label class=" text-info">Return</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    //Depart & Return Date Time Picker
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        todayBtn: true
    });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the below:

1. Write event for clicks on "Today" and "Tomorrow" selection to update your "*Month/Day/Day*" displayed.
2. Wire up the onselect event of the DatePicker, i.e when a date is selected use this date selected to  update your "*Month/Day/Day*" displayed.

This way you should be able to get this done.

Comment: Can you please tell me in details?

Answer (score 0):

here's the html to get the layout you're looking for, using only bootstrap classes:

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <label class="text-info">Depart</label>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Today</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Tomorrow</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <label class="text-info">Return</label>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Today</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Tomorrow</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I need the javascript to update date field on click with today or tomorrow. And the date to be shown as my second image, not on textfield.

Comment: In that case you could use the F12 tools in the browser to look at the styles at work in the control you're attempting to reproduce.